# How to install Nativescript to a sidekick nativescript app without error?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, nativescript

### Intro

Hi, it's my very first application with Nativescript, I'm not familiar with app developpment and with Angulair or Vue. So i used javascript to developp it.

I use Sidekick to start and build my app. I launched a test version in Android play store and at this time, I'm trying to connect Firebase to my app.

### Firebase plugin install (EddyVerbruggen)

I installed the plugin by sidekick directly or by commande line
`tns plugin add nativescript-plugin-firebase`

### Spec

**Sidekick**
* Version: 1.16.2-v.2019.3.13.12
* NativeScript CLI version: 5.3.0
* CLI extension nativescript-cloud version: 1.17.3
* CLI extension nativescript-starter-kits version: 0.3.5

**tns files**
* Component tns-core-modules has 5.3.1 version and is up to date.
* Component tns-android has 5.3.1 version and is up to date.
* Component tns-ios has 5.3.1 version and is up to date.

### Code

In app/app.js

```
const application = require("tns-core-modules/application");

const firebase = require("nativescript-plugin-firebase");

firebase.init({
  // Optionally pass in properties for database, authentication and cloud messaging,
  // see their respective docs.
}).then(
    function () {
      console.log("firebase.init done");
    },
    function (error) {
      console.log("firebase.init error: " + error);
    }
);

application.run({ moduleName: "app-root" });
```

Once I require nativescript-plugin-firebase, the app is crashing.

Files are well in /node_modules/nativescript-plugin-firebase

- google-services.json from firebase is on app/App_Resources/Android/

### Error

Error: com.tns.NativeScriptException: Failed to find module: "nativescript-plugin-firebase", relative to: app/tns_modules/

### Edit

I copied "nativescript-plugin-firebase" directory and files to platforms\android\app\src\main\assets\app\tns_modules but it still fails.

Answer (score 2):

You need to install the `nativescript-plugin-firebase` plugin before being able to use it in the application. More info on installing packages can be found in the [Sidekick documentation](https://docs.nativescript.org/sidekick/user-guide/configure-app/plugins-management). The same can be achieved from the [CLI as well](https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/plugins).

Comment: Hello @anthares It has been installed, from Sidekick... deleted... and after with the command "tns plugin add nativescript-plugin-firebase"

Answer (score 0):

In fact, some depencies were missing (adj keywords)

Answer (score 0):

do `const firebase = require("tns-core-modules/nativescript-plugin-firebase");` since {N} 5.3 you need to declare absolute paths